# Get full name from mail header regex

Tags: regex, outlook, power-automate

I want to parse the email header to get the name from this format

`From: "Firstname Lastname" <firstname_lastname@domain.com>`

I was able to get the above using this regex

`From:\s*(.*[^\s])\s*<\s*(.*[^\s])\s*>`

But I just want to extract this `Firstname Lastname`

I've been at it all day and cannot figure it out.

I am working with Power Automate to get the header of an email and extract the sender's first and last name of the sender.

Thank you.

I tried this regex
`From:\s*(.*[^\s])\s*<\s*(.*[^\s])\s*>`

it got close, but not what I wanted.

Comment: Ok but what are you using to execute the regex? Is it desktop or cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I want to parse the email header to get the name from this format ..."*

For reference, here is the RFC for, *"Common Internet Message Headers"*.
*[RFC 2076 – Common Internet Message Headers – 3.4, Sender and recipient indication](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2076#section-3.4)*.

You can use the following pattern to capture the text.

```
From:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"?\s*<
```

> *"... I tried this regex
> `From:\s*(.*[^\s])\s*<\s*(.*[^\s])\s*>`
>
>
>
> it got close, but not what I wanted."*

Just add the *quotation marks* outside of the *capture group*.

```
From:\s*\"(.*[^\s])\"\s*<\s*(.*[^\s])\s*>
```

On a final note, you can use a *match pattern*, although it will not work for all *regex engines*.

```
(?<=From: *").+?(?=")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can a name have a `"` in it? If not then how about the pattern: double-quote anything-else double-quote? That would give us:

- [`"([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/AHHwTv/1)

For example:

[image]